# Can I use the data given to Joi.validate() function instead of the result.value that it returns

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, validation, joi

**The documented way:**

```
 const data = {...someDataHere}


 const { error, value } = joi.validate(data, schema);

 if (error) return console.log(error);

    
...do stuff using `value` here
```

**Using try/catch:**

```
const data = {...someDataHere}

try {
  const { error, value } = joi.validate(data, schema);

  if (error) throw new Error(error)
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}

...do stuff using `data` here since we can not access `value`
```

**Question:**

*In regards to Joi validation library*

Since I can't access `value` here because it's in a try/catch block, can I use `data` instead? Is it the **exact same data** all the time? And is safe/okay?